# Save new record in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a litte problem about save new record to database by using Entity framework.

Here the code:

```
using (_context)
                {
                    _context.AddToStudent(newStudent);
                    _context.AddToStudentInfo(newStudentInfo);
                    _context.SaveChanges();                   
                    return true;
                }
```

My question is : If 1 of 2 _context.AddTo fail so the SaveChanges will be terminated or it will save the one success ??? I appreciate any answer :)

Comment: It won't save until you call savechanges() on your context. Savechanges persists the pending changes to the database, so the changes do not register to the db until you call that method. If an exception happens and the code terminates early, no changes will be saved at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SaveChanges() will either execute all the unexecuted operations on the database or none of them (if for example there is an error).
Thus in this case if there is an error in the newStudentInfo object (such as a required property not being set) then neither newStudentInfo or newStudent will be saved to the database.

Comment: More specifically, `SaveChanges` does all of its work within a `Transaction`.  If there is an error anywhere during the method, the `Transaction` is rolled back.